# Memory leak createCGImage in iOS9.2

Tags: uiimageview, swift2, xcode7, blur, ios9.2

I am using the following which works properly earlier. But I am getting the memory leak in iOS 9.2 and Xcode 7.

```
var context: CIContext!
var currentFilter: CIFilter!
context = CIContext(options: nil)
currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
let beginImage = CIImage(image: back)
currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

let cgimg = context.createCGImage(currentFilter.outputImage!, fromRect: rec)

let processedImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)

back = processedImage
```

Screenshot of memory leak as follows

[image]

Please let me know how can I remove this memory leak.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?